# Does IBM Watson provide support for all the locations?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, curl, php-curl

I wanted to use IBM Watson so does it provide support for all the locations? In their docs they have mentioned it does not provide support for all the locations.

> All locations might not support Speech to Text. For details, see Service availability.

Please let me know and where I can get the curl script and how to run it on my website page. Please guide me.

I have got credentials but I don't know how to use them.

In the docs they have said:

> Make sure that you have the curl command.

What curl commands should I use?

I expect an answer for how I can use those credentials for an Indian location and if it is possible, then how to use them?

Comment: why dont you just click on "Service availability"?
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/resources?topic=resources-services_region
But this will only tell you where the services are hosted. You can use services from anywhere no matter where they are hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find guidance and all necessary curl commands:

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text

Infos on Language support can be found here:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-models&locale=de

I dont see indian language among the supported languages.

If you need more help, please specify your questions.

Comment: no need of indian language support if it is  only english no problem, but curl is asking for username and password so which one should i enter don't know.

Comment: you will need an instance of the stt service to use it. You'll need to register and create one. Then you'll get your credentials.

Comment: what is stt service Please let me know how i should create

Comment: you need to register at https://cloud.ibm.com there you can create a SpeechToText Service (stt). Then you will be able to use it.